# Asynchronous ActionMailer - some emails don't get sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, gmail, actionmailer

I have a Rails app that uses ActionMailer conected with a gmail account to send email notifications.
Recently I put the "sending mail" feature on separate threads so the main request thread doesn't get blocked.

The problem is that some mails don't get sent. In the rails logs it says that the emails were sent, but if I open gmail in the browser and I look at the "sent" section, there are several mails missing.

I presume there is a "too many requests" error somewhere, because the mails are sent asynchronously, very fast. Does it help if I put an incremental delay in every thread? Is there a standard "cool-down" time after which sending mails is ok?

I don't want to use delayed job or other alternatives.

Comment: Are you sure that your problem isn't "*some emails don't get received*"? After all, the Rails logs says that they're being sent. Can you have a look at your **mailer** logs?

Comment: If they don't get recieved, then why can't I see them in my Gmail account "sent mail" section?

Comment: Could be rate-limiting, could be the content's perceived as spam, could be anything else. If the answer's anywhere, it's probably in your mail logs.